# "send ... both me and ..." vs "send ... both myself and ..."

Tags: word-choice, grammar, pronouns, reflexives

Which is correct/preferable in the context of a third party sending file X via email: "please send X to both me and Ann" or "please send X to both myself and Ann" and why? Google returns hundreds of millions of results for both.

Same question for a different word order:"please send both me and Ann X [once it's ready]" vs "please send both myself and Ann X [once it's ready]". Or is such a word order wrong altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) "please send X to both me and Ann"
>   2) "please send X to both myself and Ann"
>   3) "please send both me and Ann X [once it's ready]"
>   4) "please send both myself and Ann X [once it's ready]"

This is the classic "me, myself, and I" question.

The classic solution: remove everyone else[<sup>1</sup>](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/myself):

> 1) "please send X to me"
>   2) "please send X to myself"
>   3) "please send me X [once it's ready]"
>   4) "please send myself X [once it's ready]"

It should be clear that 1 and 3 are preferable.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was trying to figure out: whether introducing Ann might change the pronoun.

Comment: It does not, though the formally correct order is to place yourself last. E.g. "...Ann and me." Pretty sure none of those uses of "myself" are grammatically correct, but use has become quite sloppy.